# Tree with linked structure and node leafs

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, breadcrumbs, nodes

I am working with Drupal 6 and i need to create a 3 level tree with 2 levels of links(topic and subtopic) and a third level of faqs. 
Example:

```
Topic1
--Subtopic1
----FaqA
----FaqB
--Subtopic2
----FaqC
----FaqD
----FaqE
--Subtopic3
----FaqF
----FaqG
Topic2
--Subtopic4
----FaqH
----FaqI
----FaqJ
--Subtopic5
----FaqK
----FaqL
--Subtopic6
----FaqM
----FaqN
----FaqO
```

The thing important to me is that:
I am in the root(home)-> I need to see all the topics and subtopics;
I click on a topic -> I need to see all the subtopics of that topic;
I click on a subtopic -> I need to see all titles of the faqs of that subtopic;
I click on a faq title -> I need to see the full faq node;

Each page need to have a breadcrumb that shows where the user is.
The topic and subtopic pages have just a list of links to childrens, so i don't know if they have to be nodes, so maybe i just need the Faqs to be node, but i don't know how to build the topic and subtopic structure and from my tests i didn't find anything fitting (i have checked "book" content, cck, custom breadcrumb, node hierarchy and many other)
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have used this piece of code, palced on the "header" of the view, to obtain my goal:

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term(arg(1));
$parent = current(taxonomy_get_parents(arg(1)));
$name = $term->name;
echo "<h5>".$parent->name."</h5>"; //topic
echo "<h2>".$name."</h2>"; //subtopic
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Topic', 'Topicview');
$breadcrumb[] = l(drupal_get_title(), base_path() . request_uri());
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
```